# how to combine two modules in angular js if i want to use ngRoute as well as ngMessages in one ng-app.Can anyone Tell how to use it on js file?

Tags: angularjs

**how to combine two modules in angular js if i want to use ngRoute as well as ngMessages in one ng-app.Can anyone Tell how to use it on js file as it is showing error like above on doing both together**

```
     /*This is the code*/
     var myapp=angular.module('loginapp',['ngRoute','ngMessages']);

     **Error**
       **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=loginapp&p1=Error%3…d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fangularauth%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A19**%3A219)
```

Comment: its not because of both are together, but most likey because of can't load one of them. have you included proper modules in html?

Answer (score 2):

I got it the right answer as shown below

```
     ****app.js*****
```

var myapp = angular.module('app',['ngRoute','messagesExample']);

```
     ******Messages.js**********
```

var messages =angular.module('messagesExample',['ngMessages']);

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare the variable. You should declare your angular modules directly like this:

```
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]);
```